# Implementing a URL redirect in Java webapp

Tags: java, redirect

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create issue a redirect to the browser after a certain condition in a Java webapp running on Tomcat.  I'm sure there must be a simple solution, but my Java skills are extremely limited.

Here's the specific code I'm working with (copied from [guacamole-auth-passthrough](https://github.com/edouardswiac/guacamole-auth-passthrough/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/edouardswiac/guacamole/ext/PassthroughAuthProvider.java#L33)):

```
if (req.getParameter("username") == null {
  LOG.error("username is required");
  throw new GuacamoleServerException("username is required");
}
```

I'd like to replace that exception with a redirect back to the index page.  In PHP I could simply do this:

```
header("Location: https://site.domain.com/",TRUE,302);
```

Java's not letting me off so easily, though.  The best direct analog I could find is this:

```
response.sendRedirect("https://site.domain.com/");
```

However, that fails compilation with:

```
[ERROR] /home/dev/guacamole-client-0.9.9/extensions/guacamole-auth-passthrough/src/main/java/com/github/edouardswiac/guacamole/ext/PassthroughAuthProvider.java:[31,6] error: cannot find symbol
```

I've found many other examples of Java redirects (including this other [stackoverflow thread](/questions/17955777/redirect-to-an-external-url-from-controller-action-in-spring-mvc)), but almost all of them seem to implement separate methods to implement the redirect.  As I said, my java skills are very basic, and I have no idea how to actually implement something like that to be used/called from within an if condition.

Can anyone provide some pointers on how I can correctly implement this within the condition above?  I'm pretty much completely out of ideas at this point, and would very much appreciate any guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're hand-writing servlets. Is there a reason you're not using an easier toolkit such as Spring MVC?

Comment: Only because I'm reusing an existing extension for a J2EE app.  I just need to modify the code to better suit my environment, and I'm nowhere near competent enough with java to completely rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write `response.sendRedirect()` in the catch block of the exception. For example:

```
HttpServletResponse response = credentials.getResponse();
try{
  if (req.getParameter("username") == null {
    LOG.error("username is required");
    throw new GuacamoleServerException("username is required");
  }
catch(GuacamoleServerException e){
  response.sendRedirect("https://site.domain.com/");
}
```

P.S. This is provided you are using Java Servlets for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I still get the same "cannot find symbol" compilation error on the line containing the sendRedirect.  Do I maybe need to import an additional class?  here's the current list of imported non-guacamole-related classes:

org.slf4j.Logger;
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
java.util.HashMap;
java.util.Map;

Comment: @Jared Is the method in which you are writing this code has a `HttpServletResponse` param?

Comment: That string doesn't appear in the .java file.  You can view the whole file at the link in the original post (named guacamole-auth-passthrough) - it's pretty short, and, to be completely honest, you can probably figure out the answer yourself better/faster than I'd be able to explain it.

Comment: @Jared Check my updated code. I assumed that `Credentials` provide response.

Comment: Thanks again, Jagrut.  Still no go (same error, now at the HttpServletResponse line), but that got me looking at the [org.glyptodon.guacamole.net.auth.Credentials](http://guac-dev.org/doc/guacamole-ext/org/glyptodon/guacamole/net/auth/Credentials.html) documentation, and sure enough there's nothing about a Response included in the methods, so I guess that means I can't send a response directly.  Can I maybe create a new method or something to handle the redirect and then call that from within Credentials?